# if database table exists then delete it, and create one new with custom fields

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

step by step i try to write my VBA program in .net

there are one short description of how program run, 
the user selects one folder with some files with the goods stock from inventory (usually he can find 3 files, one for each the last 3 year, but is possible that the year file was 2).
the xls file has 4 columns (article code, description, quantity, total value)

- In VBA I add one sheet and I copy the contents off each file into
  this new sheet starting from column 2 ("B") in the 1st column ("A") I
  write the corresponding year.
- In .net I already wrote the code to import each file, in this case I've one mdf database and one specific table.

then in the second case I've one table with 5 fields year, codart, descr, quantity, value.

so:

- in VBA I count DISTINCT year and with ADODB I create one dynamic across query, I use codart,descr as table rows and alla year found like a columns (quantity + yr, value + yr) then this is result:
  [image]
- In .net I know how to count number of years imported, so I need a table with the necessary fields. I googled, asked Here and everywhere about how to do it, but each example that I find is how to add one mdf table from Visual Studio (Sql Server Object explorer) but I need to crete this new table by code programmatically.

can someone guide me to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you need to reword your question a little, I've re-read it a few times and I'm still quite unsure what you're trying to achieve.  Is it create a table at runtime in your DB or is it a query from you DB that gives you a result set?  And what does VBA have to do with anything?  If you're trying to do this in vba, you might need to add that to you tags

Comment: @Hursey My VBA program run right, I wish to convert it to .net, and isn't always easy. But, in this case was like "when you are desperately looking for glasses but these are on your head": I add my solution, any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

I found how to add one table to self database.

```
Private Sub Add_table()
   Dim qry As String = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_db] " &
                    "([CODPRO] NVARCHAR (50) Not NULL, [DESPRO] NVARCHAR (90) NOT NULL," &
                    "[2017quantity] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, [2017value] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " &
                    "[2018quantity] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, [2018value] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, " &
                    "[2019quantity] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, [2019value] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL)"

        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;")
            con.Open()
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(qry, con)
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
            End Try
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Then I add some check (if table exist,...)

Answer (score 0):

Take the table `test` in `LocalDatabase` as an example:

[image]

The result:

[image]

You can try my code as follows:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Public constr As String = "Data Source = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security = True ;AttachDbFileName= D:\Database\Local Database\julietest0602.mdf"
    Public conn As SqlConnection
    Public sda As SqlDataAdapter
    Public cmd As SqlCommand
    Public dt As New DataTable
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using conn = New SqlConnection(constr)
            conn.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(Select * From sysobjects Where Name='test') drop table test", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Delete OK!")


            cmd = New SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE test
                    ([CODPRO] NVARCHAR (50) Not NULL, [DESPRO] NVARCHAR (90) NOT NULL,
                    [2017quantity] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, [2017value] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, 
                    [2018quantity] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, [2018value] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, 
                    [2019quantity] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL, [2019value] FLOAT(53) NOT NULL)", conn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Create OK!")

            cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from test ", conn)
            sda = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt1 As New DataTable
            sda.Fill(dt1)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt1

        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Using conn = New SqlConnection(constr)
            conn.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from test ", conn)
            sda = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt1 As New DataTable
            sda.Fill(dt1)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt1

        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```